# Removing punctuations when reading text file [python]

Tags: python

I'm writing a python program that reads in the content of a text file into an array/list but I'm having trouble removing the punctuations from the text file. Here's what I've tried:

```
def read_file(self,filename):
    name_file = filename
    filename = open(name_file, 'r')
    file = filename
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    no_punct = ""
    lst = []
    for word in file:
        word = word.strip('\n')
        for char in punctuations:
            word = word.strip(char)
        lst.append(word)


    filename.close()
```

In the part where i strip the char, i noticed that the order of the contents in the word file is also changed and some punctuations are not entirely removed.

If i use the 'replace' method, it works well but I'm looking for a method that doesn't utilise the replace built in function.

Comment: Why don't you want to use replace? It'd be the easiest

Comment: Can you add the line that calls this function?

Comment: What is the format of your input text file? E.g. has your text file got a new word on each line or is it all a block of text?

Comment: @Worm its in the form of an ebook text file. In other words, it has paragraphs of words.

Comment: @Worm I'm not encouraged to use replace.

Comment: you also might want to use string.punctuation method from the sting module.

Answer (score 2):

Some things that I noticed that contribute to only some of the punctuation being removed. The line `for word in file:` should actually be `for line in file:`. Python iterates over files by lines and not by words. The `strip` function only removes items from the beginning and end. You would use the `replace` function to remove characters from the middle. The way the program is currently written, it will only remove punctuation from the beginning and end of each line in the document.

The way I would remove all punctuation is like so.

```
from pathlib import Path
import string

filepath = Path(filename)
text = filepath.read_text()
text = text.replace(string.punctuation, "")
filepath.write_text(text )
```

But you say that the replace function messes with the ebook functionality. Can you expound on this some more. I don't see how replacing punctuation within each individual word is any different then replacing it all at once for the entire file?